# Visual estudio c# problemas con la fecha al mostrar de bd

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

**Estoy haciendo una conexión a BD sql-server pero al traer los datos la fecha me lo trae con la hora, solo requiero la fecha como le podría hacer?**

```
            String Num_Control = txtNControl.Text;
            String Nombre = txtNombre.Text;
            String Apellido_Paterno = txtAPaterno.Text;
            String Apellido_Materno = txtAMaterno.Text;
            String Correo = txtCorreo.Text;
            String Curp = txtCurp.Text;
            String Fecha_Nacimiento = txtFecha.Text;`
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**De igual forma si dejo y quiero guardar la fecha sin modificar, como lo trae la bd me genera un error como puedo solucionar **

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué tipos de datos estás usando? SQL Server tiene un tipo de dato DATE desde la versión 2008, si usas otro tipo lo va traer con hora a menos que le des formato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para visualizar la fecha puede aplicar formato usando

```
txtFecha.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Fecha_Nacimiento"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

pero necesitas primero que sea un `DateTime` para poder aplicar el formato a string

Para insertar si el campo es de fecha en la db denes asignar al parametro un `DateTime`

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", Convert.ToDateTime(txtFecha.Text));
```

Si asignas una fecha valida lo asignara al campo al insertar o actualizar, pero tiene que ser una fecha valida, sino deberias agregar validacion de formatode la fecha que el usuario ingresa.